# In a react components, how to get latest data from state once it is changed from another component using redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

There are three components in my code.

- `cart.js`
- `datepicker.js`
- `usertotal.js`

And an action to get the data from the database

- `action.js`

And a reducer function handling actions from `actions.js`

Each component has been receiving data through action `{dispatch}`.

I need to change the data using action (if the component’s state is changed) and then hand it back to other components in my app.

How is this constructed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to use `connect` and `mapStateToProps` for this requirement.
What we need to do is use connect function from `react-redux`, your component would look something like this -:

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {Component} from "react";

class YourComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = props.data;
    }
    // Your component code.....
}

export const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  data: state.data,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(YourComponent);
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you have hooked up your redux store into your react application, using the approach recommended by @Abhisar. Your component automatically watches your state for changes and re-renders whenever there is a change in your redux state.

Also, see the official [React Redux Doc](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect)